# Why won't my layouts in Swift UI behave correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I’m definitely new to SwiftUI. Why is it that when I run this code, the `ZStack` fills the entire screen, but the letters are smooshed in the middle?  The letters won’t move to the left and right of the screen where I want them, even though I have the leading and trailing alignments on the `VStack`s.  This should keep them nice and separated, but it’s like they want to gravitate to the center.

```swift
ZStack {
            Color(.red)
            if viewstate == 0 {
            Text("Tap the screen to start the game!")
                    }
            if viewstate == 1 {
                                   VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {
                Text("P\n" + String(playerpos)).font(.system(size: 28)).accessibility(label: Text("player: " + String(playerpos)))
            })
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0, content: {
                Text("C\n" + String(comppos)).font(.system(size: 28)).accessibility(label: Text("computer: " + String(comppos)))
                    })
                            }
            }
        .frame(Width: .infinity, Height: .infinity)
```

Comment: `Text().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! V, H and ZStacks are so confusing. I think I have a handle on them now though.

Answer (score 0):

I do not the know the whole structure of your code. but you just need to add the Texts in the same VStack instead adding them in separate VStacks .and then you can just add the spacing, just like i added 20.

```
@State var viewstate = 0
let playerpos = "playerpos"
let comppos = "comppos"

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(.red)
        if viewstate == 0 {
            Text("Tap the screen to start the game!")
                .onTapGesture {
                    viewstate = 1
                }
        }
        if viewstate == 1 {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20, content: {
                Text("P\n" + String(playerpos)).font(.system(size: 28)).accessibility(label: Text("player: " + String(playerpos)))
                    .border(Color.blue,width: 1)
                Text("C\n" + String(comppos)).font(.system(size: 28)).accessibility(label: Text("computer: " + String(comppos)))
                    .border(Color.blue,width: 1)
            }).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 500)
            .border(Color.blue,width: 2)
        }
    }
}
```

for any person that is new to SwiftUI or having trouble figuring out what is happening with the Views and why are they are not were they suppose to be, just add border with color and width

```
       .border(Color.blue,width: 2)
```

that way it will become very clear that what is happening.